# Can macOS Monterey alter the text input menu to show only flag icon?

Tags: macos, keyboard, menu-bar, monterey, language

In pre-Monterey versions, the text input menu item, if enabled, only showed a representative flag icon. As of macOS Monterey, it shows the flag icon *and* a textual description. This unnecessarily crowds the menu bar, and issue further compounded by the reduced space available on the MacBook Pro M1 with the notch.

Screenshot attached. *Please note, I'm not making any kind of political statement. I'm a linguist specializing in Slavic languages.*

[image: Language input menu]

I can solve the crowding issue with Bartender - that's fine.

Is there a hidden preference to revert to the flag-only display, or some other workaround to omit the long text in the menu bar?

Comment: If by chance you would like to have a different icon for Russian, since that language is used in so many other countries besides the one using that flag, see  http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2022/02/macos-russian-keyboard-layouts-without.html

Comment: @TomGewecke Thank you. I just may do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try clicking on the item labeled "Hide Input Source Name" at the bottom of your picture:

[image]

Comment: Doh. Thank you. How many times have I looked at that yet did not see it?